# Index ActionMethod in Home Controller would be called twice in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i created an ASP mvc 4 project with basic template and just with one Index view .
when i run the application , Index Method that belongs to Home Controller called twice.
i cant understand why
please help me
Thanks Alot

Index Method:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Index View :

```
    @{
         Layout = null;
     }

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: meanwhile I have No Model in project

Comment: You have to show a little bit of code for that.

Comment: The probable condition occuring can be "loading of javascripts twice".

Comment: @EhsanShirvan. Do you mind post some of your code here? so that it is easier for us to figure it out:)

Comment: are you using umbraco? yes, ive had that problem before with it...piece of crap. but seriously, did you try a fresh new project?

Comment: i should note that i added a breakpoint on Index()  method and in Debug mode, i recieved breakpoint twice

Comment: @Ahmedilyas what is umbraco? and i should say Yes i tried a new project and again i got this situation too

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the problem
i always test my project on google chrome after changing browser and agin run the project on IE it did not occour the problem again
so my browser which was set in VS2012 , and its setting was the problem